# Hamming distance of Bernoulli RV

Tags: distance, bernoulli-distribution

Assume you draw $k$ data points out of $n$ data points. Each data point is composed of $m$ Bernoulli random variables. You may assume that the data points are i.i.d and likewise their coordinates, but if you can provide an answer without this assumption it would be better.

Consider point $i$ of the $n$ data points, and find the nearest point (in terms of the Hamming distance) from the set of $k$ points. Think of it as point $i$'s representative. Pick some coordinate  (one of the $m$ coordinates) - what is the probability that the nearest neighbor (=representative) of $i$ will disagree with $i$ on that coordinate?

Comment: How do you decide tie breaks between nearest neighbors?

Comment: Well,whichever you decide: Optimally, by random choice  amongst the nearest representatives. Otherwise,  if there exists a nearest representative with a different coordinate then pick it (upper bound).